# How to reset do while loop within while loop?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, do-while

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int comp,loop=1,tcomp=0;
char cont;
char name[50];
float donate=0,total,gtotal;

printf("\nGot representative? [Y to continue]: ");
scanf("%s", &cont);

while(cont=='y'){
    printf("\nRepresentative name : ");
    scanf("%s", &name);
    printf("How many companies? : ");
    scanf("%d", &comp);
    tcomp+=comp;
    do{
        printf("Enter amount of donation : ");
        scanf("%f", &donate); loop++;
        total+=donate;}
        while(loop<=comp);
    printf("%s : %.2f\n", name, total);

    printf("\nGot representative? [Y to continue]: ");
    scanf("%s", &cont);}


    printf("\nTotal Representative : %d", tcomp);
    gtotal+=total;
    printf("\nTotal Donations : %.2f\n", gtotal);
}
```

Current output :

```
Got representative? [Y to continue]: y

Representative name : ABC

How many companies? : 3

Enter amount of donation : 1

Enter amount of donation : 2

Enter amount of donation : 3

ABC : 6.00

Got representative? [Y to continue]: y

Representative name : ZXC

How many companies? : 3

Enter amount of donation : 1

ZXC : 7.00
```

As you can see here, the 2nd loop did not reset and it's summing the numbers of first loop. How do I rectify this? How do I make it that the loop starts fresh each time? p/s : I was asked specifically to use while and do while loop.

Comment: Did you have a look at the warning the compiler spits out ?

Comment: Make loop = 0 in outer while loop.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &cont)` should be `scanf("%c", &cont)` and `total` and `gtotal` are used without being initialized. What compiler do you use ?

Comment: Please fix the indention before posting code on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below your corrected code.

```
int main()
{

    int comp,loop=1,tcomp=0;
    char cont;
    char name[50];
    float donate=0,total=0,gtotal=0;

    printf("\nGot representative? [Y to continue]: ");
    scanf("%c", &cont);

    while(cont=='y')
    {
        printf("\nRepresentative name : ");
        scanf("%s", name);
        printf("How many companies? : ");
        scanf("%d", &comp);
        tcomp+=comp;
        loop=0;
        total=0;
        do
        {
            printf("Enter amount of donation : ");
            scanf("%f", &donate); loop++;
            total+=donate;
        }
        while(loop<comp);

        printf("%s : %.2f\n", name, total);

        printf("\nGot representative? [Y to continue]: ");
        scanf("%c", &cont);
        gtotal+=total;
    }


    printf("\nTotal Representative : %d", tcomp);
    printf("\nTotal Donations : %.2f\n", gtotal);

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see:

1. You must reset `loop` variable before each loop where amount are asked.
2. You must reset `total` before that loop
3. You must save to `gtotal` for each iteration of first while loop.
4. You must use %c instead of %s to get a single char: `scanf("%c", &cont);`

Comment: I know that I have to use %c for a single character, but for some reason my code would stop running after the first loop if I use %c. Do you happened to know why? (I use codeblock)